# Weirdest javaScript array literal

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

when I was on my project, I accidentally named a array "name" like this

```
var name = ["abc","abc","abc","abc"];
```

it generated an inconsistency in my project because as I expected name[0] would yield the first abc, HOWEVER!, it gives me the first letter a!!!. I tried this array in Firefox console and it always gave my the array instead of a String which I got from typing this into Chrome console.
   So I renamed the variable to be something else like this in Chrome again

```
var foo = ["abc","abc","abc","abc"];
```

And foo[0] gave me the first "abc". Feel free to try this, I am guessing there is a problem with the naming "name", but have no idea why. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the top level `var name` is the same as `window.name`.

[`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.name) is reserved, so Chrome 
converts it to string implicitly.

Note that converting an array to a string just comma-separates it:

```
["abc","abc","abc","abc"].toString()
```

is:

```
"abc,abc,abc,abc"
```

Comment: And this is why we don't use global variables.

Comment: I agree we should be careful with global variables, but you often want to use a couple (e.g. library objects).

Comment: the weird part is that my "name" array is wrapped in a function.. O_o

Comment: You said you did in the console?

Comment: My bad, there is a bug in my code, so I copied a big chunk into the console which includes the array, sorry man

Comment: it should be the Chrome thing, I will take a look at it. Thank you all

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen you want _one_ for your modularization tool

Answer (score 2):

The [Window object](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#window) has a [name](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#dom-name) property which is specified as follows:

> The name attribute of the Window object must, on getting, return the current name of the browsing context, and, **on setting, set the name of the browsing context to the new value.**

(emphasis mine)

Thus, setting `window.name`, by e.g. doing `var window = ...` in a global context, will set the name of the browsing context to the right-hand side. Since the name must be a string, the setter converts it to one.